# Clarification about Ikshvaku lineage

Tags: ramayana, rama, ganga, suryavansh, harishchandra

As per story, Raja Harishchandra was 33<sup>rd</sup> descendant of Ikshvaku family. Bhagiratha was 44<sup>th</sup> and Rama 63<sup>rd</sup>.

Raja Harishchandra worked on ghats of Benares cremation grounds on banks of Ganga but Ganga should come after Bhagiratha because Bhagiratha brought Ganga to the Earth by his tapa.

On which river bank was Raja Harishchandra working? Was it Ganga?

How could Ganga be present at the time of Harishchandra when it is brought to earth by his descendant Bagiratha?

Comment: Your title and body are not related. Do you want to know lineage of Rama from Harichandra or do you want to know in which Ghat Harishchandra worked?

Comment: Obviously it must be Ganga as Varnasi has Ganga.

Comment: But if Ganga then how come it was present at the time of Harishchandra?

Comment: which scriptures tells he was at banks of ganga or some river , if you can quote it , it will help others to answer question?

Answer (score 3):

As per the chapter [Harishchandra of Brahma Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/brahma_purana/harishchandra.html)

> "How can I obtain a son?" asked Harishchandra.
>
> "Go to the banks of the **Goutami Ganga**," advised the sages.

So this Ganga was not Bhagirathi Ganga but Goutami Ganga.

**If Ganga was already there then why Bhagirath brought Ganga again?**

As per *Bala Kanda of Valmiki Ramayana*, Lord Shri Rama ruled for 11,000 years and his earlier generations even more (Anshuman - 32,000 years, Dilipa - 30,000 years). So from 33rd to 44th generation there is huge gap in term of years.

It might be possible that Ganga was on Earth earlier but due to some reason left the Earth. And later Bhagiratha brought Ganga to Earth again.

This might be same as

> Goddess Lakshmi was emerged during Samundra Manthan but before that she was born as daughter of Khyati.

Similarly, few stories are related to Ganga:

As per [SRISHTI KHAND - Padma Purana](https://vedpuran.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/padam-puran.pdf) (page 96), Ganga originated from Lord Vishnu's feet.

As per the chapter [Vishnu and Manu of Matsya Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/matsya_purana/vishnu_and_manu.html), Ganga was there before the the beginning of Vaivasvata Manavantar i.e. (even when Ikshvaku was not born). But as deluge (प्रलय) happened after that so many people brought Ganga on Earth again.

I. As per [Last Chapter of Skanda Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/skanda_purana/the_sanctity_of_dwarkapuri.html),

> Lord Brahma instructed Ganga by saying- ' Ganga! Go to the earth, where you would be known as **Gomti**. Sage Vashishtha will lead you to your destination. Just follow him like a daughter follows her father.'

II. As per the chapter [The Origin of Trayambakeshwar - PART FOUR KOTI RUDRA SAMHITA of Shiva Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/shiva_purana/the_origin_of_trayambakeshwar.php), Sage Gautam requested Lord Shiva to liberate him from the sins of killing a cow. He also requested lord Shiva to manifest the stream of river Ganga that place. This Ganga became famous as **Gautami Ganga**.

III. Daughter of Himvana (sister of Parvati)

IV. Bhagiratha brought Ganga on Earth, this Ganag is known as **Bhagirathi Ganga**.

V. As per [Sambhava Parva - Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01097.htm), Lord Bhrahma cursed both Mahabhisha and Ganga to take birth in Mrityu loka (Ganga in Mahabharata as wife of Shantanu)